# Get files from index subdirectory (htaccess)

Tags: php, .htaccess

I made a routes class in php, the routes works fine but i have a problem, when i put something like:

```
.ng-perfil-avatar {
  display: block;
  background: #eee url(/img/bg.png);
}
```

in the view, the img not is founded, my web is in subdirectory /web/ and when i get a file (img for example) It is seek in: `localhost/img/bg.png` I need look at `localhost/web/img/bg.png

(GET http://127.0.0.1/img/bg.png 404 (Not Found))

how i can configure .htaccess to automatically to search the directory (not having to be adding /web/ or changing the variable if in a subdirectory)`

my .htaccess is this:

```
Options -MultiViews

RewriteEngine On

Options -Indexes

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l

RewriteRule ^(.+)$ index.php?url=$1 [QSA,L]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a frequent problem and there are multiple solutions.

The easiest way to go (certainly in CSS) is to use relative paths instead of absolute paths. So lets say your CSS is in `web/css/style.css` and you want to set image `web/img/background.jpg` as your background. You want to refer to this image from your CSS as:

```
background: url('../img/background.jpg');
```

As it is one directory up (`web/css` to `web`) and then into the images directory.

Another tip is to use the [`base`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/HTML/Element/base) element. It lets you set the base URL of your page making all path relative to that path.